# Asp.Net MVC 3 LogIn page redirection error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, authentication

I have a very strange situation.  I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 application that all of a sudden stopped working properly.  When anyone goes to a secured URL (say /Hidden/Index) they get redirected to a login page (/Account/Login),  the only issue that I have is that my Login Page is /Session/LogOn.

I have set up the Web.Config file correctly. I have been using ASP.Net MVC since Version 1 and have never run into this issue.

My Web.Config file contains:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Session/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

And I do not have /Account/Login anywhere in my solution.  If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

There must still be code somewhere pointing to that action, if you created your app from the default mvc 3 application in visual studio, check the logon view in the solution folder named "shared", under "views".

Comment: I thought the same thing, but my Logon Partial view is pointing to the correct location.  What baffles me is the fact that I can debug the application and since the first controller is decorated with [Authorize] it redirects me to /Account/Login.  I don't even show a page first. So I am confused.  Does anyone know if there is a default route for the [Authorize] data annotation? And if so, where it is stored?  Thank you.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce this is if I have the default MVC3 app created in VS2010 and modify only the web.config under the views soln folder and NOT the web.config in the application root.  Apologies if this is stating the obvious but have you modified the auth setting in both configs?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, there may be conflicting dll's in your bin directory, have you added deployable dependencies or any recent references?

Helped me!
http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/asp-net-mvc-unauthenticated-user-always-redirected-to-accountlogon-despite-custom-sign-in-url/

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem in MVC3. The problem occurs because `WebMatrix.Data.dll` and `WebMatrix.DataWeb.dll` have been added to the deployable assemblies collection.

In order to fix the problem you need to add the following in your `Web.config` (the application root level one):

```
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/SignIn" />
</appSettings>
```